# RESTFul Service API POST CSV file

Tags: rest, csv, post, postman

We are using a student management system/CRM (axcelerate) which doesn't have bulk import tools for contacts.  but they do provide API for this.

I have tested on a coldbox module which allows me to test with single sets of parameter names and values.

It is confirmed the URL and API headers I am using are correct, the single parameter data was sent and shows up correctly in the CRM.

Now I am trying to send thousands of contacts.  I guess to do this with a CSV file and I have tried with Postman.

I have put API headers into the `Headers` section, and I have put `api.contact` as a key, and for the value, I have uploaded a CSV file that has `FIELDNAMES` same as CRM advised: I used `givenName` and `surname`.

I created Elvis and Presley as values and this is the error:

```
{
    "DATA": "",
    "ERROR": true,
    "MESSAGES": "Validation Error.",
    "CODE": 412,
    "FIELDNAMES": "givenName,surname",
    "DETAILS": "Required field givenName is undefined in the request collection.,Required field surname is undefined in the request collection."
}
```

Any advice to execute this task successfully?

Thank you.

[image: Postman screenshot of send attempt]

Comment: Is api.contact the key that you have in the csv file? The `{{...}}` placeholder syntax should match the column header from the file. Could you attach an image of what your POST body looks in Postman - it’s difficult to know your set up

Comment: Hi Danny.  i have attached image.  thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API docs](https://admin.axcelerate.com.au/apidocs/home/index) for the `/contact` route it requires you to add the `givenName` and `surname` to the URL as params

[image: API Doocs]

You could use your data file in the `Collection Runner` and reference these using the `{{...}}` placeholder syntax in the URL.

```
<basePath>/contact?givenName={{givenName}}&surname={{surname}}
```

The [Postman docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files) will explain how to add the data file to the `Collection Runner` but once added, when you run the collection, it will populate the placeholders in the URL and hopefully create the new contacts for you in the CRM tool.

Comment: i have a test csv created but have this error when importing: error while importing, format not recognized 
so, not able to run the collection.
i had this on first row:  /contact/, givenName, surname
and this on 2nd row: /contact/, elvis, presley
givenName and surname were the headers provided by the API host

Comment: What’s the /contact/ for? Have you tried it without that?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are trying to add the file in the collection runner and not the main import feature right?